# Trying to rotate a polygon using math

Tags: java, eclipse, rotation, polygon

I have a school assignment where I'm supposed to (among other things) rotate a polygon. I can not use any premade rotate functions, so I have an array of points. The array is set up like this:

`intArray[2][amount_of_points]` where `intArray[0]` equals the points x coordinate, and  `intArray[1]` holds the y coordinates.

```
    //x=pivot point x coordinate, y = pivot point y coordinate.
public int[][] rotate(int[][]matrix,int x, int y, double degrees){

    double s=Math.sin(degrees);
    double c=Math.cos(degrees);


    for (int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){

        //translate to origin
        int px=matrix[0][i]-x;
        int py=matrix[1][i]-y;

        //rotate
        double xnew = (px*c)-(py*s);
        double ynew = (px*s)+(py*c);

        //translate back
        px=(int)((xnew+x)+0.5);
        py=(int)((ynew+y)+0.5);

        matrix[0][i]=px;
        matrix[1][i]=py;
    }
```

This is my code so far, and it is definitely not working out for me. I tried to trim the code as much as I could. Any help would mean a lot!

edit: I'm not getting any errors when I run the code, no exceptions etc. The only problem is that the polygon isn't rotating the way I intend it to.

I've made a test polygon:

```
polyArray = new int [2][3];
    polyArray[0][0]=400;
    polyArray[1][0]=200;
    polyArray[0][1]=300;
    polyArray[1][1]=500;
    polyArray[0][2]=500;
    polyArray[1][2]=500;
```

Which I draw in a JPanel, then I run this array through the rotation method like this: 
    polyArray=mm.rotate(polyArray, polyArray[0][0], polyArray[1][0], Math.PI);

Using the top point as pivotpoint. The whole polygon is then deformed.

Comment: Sorry first comment was wrong, here's a picture of a polygon not rotated: http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/103/4ulx.png

then rotated by PI: http://i.imgur.com/q9t0yXU.png

The pivotpoint is the top point

Comment: I am not interested in the image.. is there any exception when you run this?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you mean by _"definitely not working out for me"_ or risk having your question put on hold.

Comment: Ok I added an explanation in my original question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although still not very clear on question, I feel your problem is with the loop.
`matrix.length is 2`. So, the code never uses these :

```
polyArray[0][2]=500;
polyArray[1][2]=500;
```

If you change the condition as below, it should work :

```
for (int i=0;i<matrix[0].length;i++)
```

Comment: G V, you are right that was the problem. I'm sorry my question wasn't very clear, I'm very tired right now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome... for future, the clearer you are with the question, the faster you get the answer :-)